# Oracle min and max columns query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Alright, need some help created a query for an Oracle 10g DB. I have a table to looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| lowerBound | upperBound | locationId |
----------------------------------------
|      0     |     99     |     1      |
----------------------------------------
|     100    |    199     |     2      |
----------------------------------------
...
```

Another table looks like this:

```
-----------------------------
| locationId | locationCode |
-----------------------------
|     1      |     12345    |
-----------------------------
|     2      |     23456    |
-----------------------------
|     3      |     34567    |
-----------------------------
...
```

I start with a number, say 113, but it is a variable figured out in java. I need to figure out the locationId that corresponds to that number, based on it falling between the lowerBound  and upperBound columns, and then join that to figure out the locationCode in the 2nd table. I've looked up things like MIN/MAX and between, however I am not finding exactly what I am looking for. I am not a good DBA, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.locationCode
  FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 USING(locationId)
 WHERE 113 BETWEEN t1.lowerBound AND t1.upperBound
```

If the USING part puzzles you:

```
SELECT t2.locationCode
  FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.locationId = t1.locationId
 WHERE 113 BETWEEN t1.lowerBound AND t1.upperBound
```

Note that this will work if your lowerBound and upperBound columns are INTEGERS. If they are VARCHAR, you will have to use the `TO_NUMBER` function of course.